# deleting from array in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Im currently having trouble deleting an item from my array in my firebase firestore. I'm able to delete it locally but when I refresh it shows up again. I know I'm supposed to use the actual value. THis is my related code and this is what the items look like in my firestore[image]

```
const removeGoalHandler = async (goalId) => {
    let goalToDel = {}
    for(let i =0; i < courseGoals.length; i++){
        if(courseGoals[i].id == goalId){
            console.log(courseGoals[i])
            goalToDel = courseGoals[i]
        }
    }
    const removeGoal = await loansRef.doc(userId).update({
        goals: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(goalToDel)
    })
    setCourseGoals((currentGoals)=> {
        return currentGoals.filter((goal)=> goal.id !== goalId)
    })
    setGoalCounter(goalCounter-1)
};

const addToFB = async (goalTitle, interestRate, years, paidOff,id) => {
    //adding data to firebase, takes into account if doc exists already 
    if(id==undefined){
        id = goalCounter
    }
    console.log('add to firebase')
    const loadDoc = await loansRef.doc(userId).get()
        .then((docSnapshot)=> {
            if(docSnapshot.exists){
                loansRef.doc(userId).onSnapshot((docu)=>{
                    console.log('num2: '+ (goalCounter+id).toString())
                    const updateLoansArr = loansRef.doc(userId).update({
                        goals: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                            id: userId+(goalCounter+id).toString(),
                            value: goalTitle,
                            interest: interestRate,
                            years: years,
                            paidOff: paidOff
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
            else{
                console.log('num3: '+ (goalCounter+id).toString())
                const addDoc = loansRef.doc(userId).set({
                    goals: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                    id: userId+(goalCounter+id).toString(),
                    value: goalTitle,
                    interest: interestRate,
                    years: years,
                    paidOff: paidOff
                })
            })
        }})
}
```

this is my code where I actually add a loan; in here it calls addToFB() which adds it to firebase haha

```
const addGoalHandler = (goalTitle, interestRate, years, paidOff,id) => {
    console.log('add goal handler')
    if(id==undefined){
        id = 0
    }
    console.log('num1: '+ (goalCounter+id).toString())
    //console.log(goalCounter)
    setGoalCounter(goalCounter+1)
    setCourseGoals((courseGoals) => [
        ...courseGoals,
        {
            id: userId + (goalCounter+id).toString(),
            value: goalTitle,
            interest: interestRate,
            years: years,
            paidOff: paidOff
        }
    ]);
    //console.log(goalCounter)
    addToFB(goalTitle, interestRate,years,paidOff,id)
    setIsAddMode(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `arrayRemove()` uses strict equality to compare array elements and determine which to remove, it doesn't compare the "ids" like you are doing in your code. Unfortunately, this means that every object would be deemed different from every other object (whether different id or same id) irrespective of how identical they are,  (`{} === {} //false`), so it doesn't find the element to remove. `arrayRemove()` would work better with an array containing primitive types: (number, string, etc).

As it stands, your best option is fetch the existing document, use your "id" logic to remove the desired element and write it back. Like so:

```js
const removeGoalHandler = async (goalId) => {
    const existingDoc = await loansRef.doc(userId).get();
    const goals = existingDoc.data().goals.filter(goal => goal.id !== goalId);
    await loansRef.doc(userId).update({ goals });
    setCourseGoals(goals);
    ...
};
```

Comment: It worked once but after that it kept adding the one I wanted to delete back to my firebase

Comment: By any chance does this issue I'm having right now have to do with my useEffect fuction

Comment: Your `useEffect()` is not the issue as it does not call any functions that write to your database (`set()`, `update()` etc). Is the `removeGoalHandler()` function the only place in your code where `doc().update()`  is being called?

Comment: no i have another one that adds to Firebase; let me upload that right now

Comment: The loan doesnt get re-added if i logout and log back in; the loan stays deleted. Im not sure why this is happening

Comment: addToFB() is called when I add a new loan

Comment: You should `console.log()` your `snapshot` from your `onSnapshot` handler in your `useEffect`. Cos it's called everytime your firestore doc is updated

Comment: Incidentally you don't need to `setGoals()` from `removeGoalHandler()` since it will get called again from your `onSnapshot` handler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219772/discussion-between-cornondajacob04-and-jay-codist).